# Face book wall posting is not working properly

Tags: php, facebook

While trying to make a wall post on facebook using PHP as the scripting language , the script stops after a successfull authentication to facebook.The code used is as given below.Please help me to solve this issue.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
         'appId' => $app_id,
         'secret' => $app_secret,
         'cookie' => true
        ));
        $fbcheck= $facebook->getUser();

        if(is_null($fbcheck) or !$fbcheck or $fbcheck==0)
        {
         header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload'))}");

        }

        $attachment = array(
        'message' => 'Hello friends , try this job :)',
        'name' => "Jobslanda - The perfect job information system. ",
        'caption' => "My Caption",
        'link' => 'google.com',
        'description' => 'Jobslanda is one of the perfect job sharing system.',
        //'picture' => $urlParser->fbpostpic($input['ik']),
        'actions' => array(array(
            'name' => 'Get Search',
            'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
        ))
    );
        $result = $facebook->api(
        '/me/feed/',
        'post',
        $attachment
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

print_r($result); Check whether it returns an id with a number.